# How to change namespace from C#

Tags: .net, wcf

I have the following code

```
namespace A
{
    [DataContract]
    public class CustomClass {}
}
```

how could I decorate the DataContract attribute, or what I must change on server side to change the code into

```
namespace B
{
    [DataContract(...)]
    public class CustomClass {}
}
```

and all existing clients to connect without problems to this client.

Note: I can't change any client, only on server side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends on what binding (and more specifically, which serializer) you are using. If you are using `DataContractSerializer`, then the answer is simple: do nothing. Those two contracts are equivalent; the wire data is defined by:

- the explicit name in `[DataContract(...)]`, if one - else the class name (which matches)
- the explicit xml namespace in `[DataContract(...)]`

If you are using `NetDataContractSerializer`, simple: you can't.

Note that the c# namespace used at the client is entirely up to the client, and is typically determined by the tooling used to generate the type. Frankly, it doesn't matter what the client uses as the c# namespace, as long as they are using a contract-based serializer such as `XmlSerializer` or `DataContractSerializer`.

To illustrate this: this prints the same thing twice:

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System;
namespace A
{
    [DataContract] class Foo { }
}
namespace B
{
    [DataContract] class Foo { }
}
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        new DataContractSerializer(typeof (A.Foo)).WriteObject(
              Console.OpenStandardOutput(), new A.Foo());
        Console.WriteLine();
        new DataContractSerializer(typeof (B.Foo)).WriteObject(
              Console.OpenStandardOutput(), new B.Foo());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The server and client use different dlls and definitions. This is obviously true because they are on different machines.

So, if the client has a definition of the server's interface in namespace **A**, it will stay that way. Because it's only an interface definition that tells the client how to call the server.

In the server you can change the namespace however you want, and it won't affect the client.

Comment: In this case, I believe you are correct - however, it is not "obviously true" - it is possible to share DTO types in a library between WCF uses